# Why different dowloaded file sizes via different method with cloudflare polish enabled?

Tags: cloudflare-polish

If I check a jpeg file in Chrome dev console, here is what I see in the 'Network' tag.

[image]

The `content-length` is 28479. If I use a 'Save Image' function in browser, the image size is exactly this.

The image file is hosted on an AWS s3 bucket. If I use `aws s3 cp` to download the file, I can see the original file size: 50578.

However when I use `wget https://files.mycompany.com/abcdefg/thumbnail_large.jpg`, I expected it to come through from cloudflare CDN and hence compressed (ie. 28479). However it is 50578.

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 antkong  staff  50578 29 Nov 00:58 thumbnail_large_from_wget.jpg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 antkong  staff  28479 18 Mar 10:25 thumbnail_large_from_browser.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 antkong  staff  50578 29 Nov 00:58 thumbnail_large_from_s3.jpg
```

Why `wget` produces a different file size this case?

I have also tried to set the `user agent` to the one sent by the browser i.e.
`wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36" 
 https://files.mycompany.com/abcdefg/thumbnail_large.jpg`. Same result.

Only three fields in the Request headers:

> Origin: https://www.mycompany.com
>
> Referer: https://www.mycompany.com
>
> User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.3

Comment: What were the request headers?

Comment: Added request headers info to the question

Comment: Are you absolutely sure those are the only request headers? Chrome should be sending many more headers than that.

Comment: Yes. And also it has this `Provisional headers are shown` line above those values

Comment: You need to get the request headers from an actual request that was sent to the server and returned a response, not from a cached or failed response.

Comment: Where else can I get this data if not from the dev console in a browser? `Disable Cache` is already used and it seems to me it does hit the server. Here is the timing breakdown: Request sent 95µs, Waiting (TTFB) 91.66ms, Content Download 0.44ms